# Open XML SDK: 'The process cannot access the file 'x' because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#, ms-office, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

This is my code that modifies a PowerPoint presentation, saves it as a new file, closes it, then tries to open that file.

```
var doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\temp.pptx", true);    
//... proccess presentation
doc.SaveAs(@"d:\temp2.pptx");
doc.Close();

var doc2 = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\temp2.pptx", false);
doc2.Close();
```

I can not understand why run-time throws an exception:

> The process cannot access the file 'x' because it is being used by
>   another process.

Comment: try saving to stream and create new file, rather than directly calling "SaveAs".

Comment: @codetoshare, `doc` is object of  [PresentationDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.presentationdocument(v=office.14).aspx)  which unfortunately has not some method to stream save.

Comment: Please post a complete enough code snippet for repro purposes; see [mcve] for more information. I'd test it for you, but I don't have the time to work up an entire project...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I noticed that `doc.SaveAs()` return object, which I closed just

```
var savedDoc = doc.SaveAs(@"d:\temp2.pptx") as PresentationDocument;

savedDoc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to open your presentation with a using statement. Something along the lines of:

```
using (var doc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"d:\temp.pptx", true))
{    
//... proccess presentation
doc.SaveAs(@"d:\temp2.pptx");
doc.Close(); //may be unnecessary
}
```